# Spring Jdbc query execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

Does anyone know how what Spring Jdbc template method I could use to execute this 'upsert' or an alternative approach that would also perform the operations in one database call?

```
UPDATE jasper_report SET Uri = 'update' WHERE ReportId = 99;
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 AND Exists(Select 1 FROM report Where Id = 99)
BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO jasper_report  (ReportId, Uri) VALUES (99, 'insert') 
END;
```

Comment: EXACT duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104211/spring-jdbc-template-query-execution

Comment: Accidentally posted twice, dup has been removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was close but forget a step.

I had to change the query itself to:

```
BEGIN 
  UPDATE jasper_report SET Uri = ? WHERE ReportId = ? 
  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM report WHERE Id = ?) 
  BEGIN 
       INSERT INTO jasper_report  (ReportId, Uri) VALUES (?, ?) 
  END 
END
```

Then in my Dao only needed to use [Spring's JdbcTemplate update method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[]%29). It looks something like this:

```
@Repository("jasperReportsDao")
public class JasperReportsDaoImpl extends JdbcTemplate implements JasperReportsDao {

    @Override
    public void saveJasperReport(JasperReport report) {
        // If a record already exists, do an update, otherwise, do an insert
        int rowsAffected = this.update(UPSERT_JASPER_REPORT, new Object[] { report.getUri(), report.getId(),
                               report.getId(), report.getId(), report.getUri()} );

        if(log.isDebugEnabled()) { log.debug("Rows affected: " + rowsAffected); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be `Not Exists`?

At any rate I think it would work fine without the `Not Exists`, since `@@ROWCOUNT` is already giving you that info:

```
UPDATE jasper_report SET Uri = 'update' WHERE ReportId = 99;
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO jasper_report (ReportId, Uri) VALUES (99, 'insert') 
END;
```

Comment: No, the exists is on a different table, essentially it is checking that the foreign key constraint exists on the primary table, thus avoiding a foreign key violation if the id is not in the 'report' table.

Comment: Oh, missed that it was a different table!